# ‎It seems/seemed that he ate a lot yesterday - what are the differences?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

> It seems that he ate a lot yesterday.

> It seemed that he ate a lot yesterday.

What are the differences in meaning?

**Example 2**

> It is unlikely that she said it.

> It was unlikely that she said it.

What are the differences in meaning?

Comment: It's purely a question of ***when*** the overeating was ***observed***. If the speaker knew nothing about the overeating *at the time*, but does now, he'd use Present Tense ***it seems***. With the "unlikely that she said it" example it's a bit different, since speaker can have a *current* view about whether or not something was likely *in the past*, so both tenses are valid. It just depends what nuance the speaker wants to give. But usually, since we're saying what we *now* think, we'd usually use Present Tense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

FumbleFingers' comment should have been an answer.  It is on point.  From a slightly different perspective, however, I would suggest the following nuances.

```
It seems that he ate a lot yesterday.
```

The implication with this sentence, using the present tense, is that the speaker did not directly witness the eating.  He or she either heard about it, or saw evidence later (such as empty food wrappers, etc.) that suggest this conclusion.  As it was not directly witnessed, it is possible that some other explanation exists (e.g. a visitor came and ate the food without the speaker's knowledge).  The "seems" indicates either uncertainty, i.e. no positive proof, or deference, i.e. not wanting to challenge the listener's view, in case it differs.

```
It seemed that he ate a lot yesterday.
```

The past tense here implies one of two things: 1) the speaker was there when this happened, and witnessed this; or 2) later evidence refutes this conclusion, i.e. "seemed" is used to invoke the *unreal* condition.  In the latter case, the next sentence could say something like, "In actual fact, when I later checked up on him, I found that he had not eaten much at all."

```
It is unlikely that she said it.
```

The speaker finds it hard to believe that the person addressed would have said such a thing.  This is present tense showing that the view expressed by the speaker is *still current.*

```
It was unlikely that she said it.
```

This sentence seems, to me, to be grammatically weak.  It would more naturally read: "It was unlikely that she **had** said it."  This would put the speaker's view into the narrative past, indicating that the speaker thought it hard to believe *at that past point in time* -- a view which may or may not still be thought true at present.

Another possibility, however, is that she had *actually* said it, which was something unexpected (unlikely) on her part.  Her having made the *unlikely* statement would have surprised the speaker who is recounting this detail.

Comment: I would disagree that example 2 could mean the speaker was there when the event happened--if so, it would be more natural to say "He ate a lot yesterday"--no inference ("seems") required. I think the unreal condition (or describing an inference that happened in the past and was subsequently confirmed or refuted) is the most natural way to read it.